# Parsing the index cache failed (Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position 16:)

Tags: haskell, cabal

I was trying to write an installation script for a project I'm working on and I had to test it by installing ghc again (don't have the resources to download vms) from the following link : `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh`. Everything works fine but when I run a project using `cabal run proj` I get the following warning where A,B stand for 32 character strings:

```
Warning: Parsing the index cache failed (Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position
16: Non-matching structured hashes: A;
expected: B). Trying to regenerate the index
cache...
```

I went to my home directory and deleted `.ghcup` and the empty `.ghc` directories. Then I went to `usr/local/bin` and found the following :

```
/usr/local/bin > ls | grep ghc
ghc
ghc-8.8.3
ghc-pkg
ghc-pkg-8.8.3
ghci
ghci-8.8.3
haddock-ghc-8.8.3
runghc
runghc-8.8.3
```

And in my Brew folder I have another instance of ghc-8.8.3. I'm really not sure if I just inadvertently screwed myself over with the installation. Would a fresh reinstall be recommended or would deleting every .ghc occurrence bar one to just have one be fine?

Comment: [1/2] (1) If there is a corrupt index cache, it shouldn't be in `~/.ghcup` or `~/.ghc`, but rather in `~/.cabal`. I suggest removing `~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3` (assuming that's the GHC version you are using) and trying again. (2) [cabal issue #6659](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6659) seems related, though I guess the extended discussion after the issue was reopened isn't relevant in your case. (3) If you are installing GHC through ghcup, you shouldn't need the one installed from Brew, and it's probably better to uninstall it. Note that ghcup doesn't install tools into `/usr`.

Comment: [2/2] (4) The two GHCs you see are probably symlinked to the same executable. I believe you'd also see that on a ghcup install; in itself, that is not a problem. (ghcup, for instance, manages multiple installations of GHC by maintaining symklinks.)

Comment: @duplode Thank you very much. Just removing `~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3` itself seems to have solved the issue

Comment: Glad it helped! I have promoted the comments to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Cabal store somehow became inconsistent along the way (cf. the initial discussion at [cabal issue #6659](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6659)). Assuming you are using GHC 8.8.3, removing `~/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3` should allow it to be recreated properly.

On a tangential note, if you plan to manage your installations of GHC, cabal-install and other tools through ghcup, you might as well remove the system-wide Brew installations, which will presumably be unnecessary.